# Ionic apk showing blank page but showing list of products in browser

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, woocommerce-rest-api

I had created a Woo Commerce site and it's in live. And then I convert my site into an ionic app using ionic woo commerce API. I have keys from woo commerce API in my site, I have configured keys into my app.

The products and categories are display in my browser. And when I build the app in android platform. the app was built successfully. But I can't found products and categories when I installed the app on my phone.

Can anyone suggest me how to solve this probem?

Comment: you can try ionic run android -l -c to check error on cli

Comment: ya i checked it, It shows ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is not defined

Comment: your sdk path is not define correctly check it

Comment: if its help you then let me know

Comment: yes but, i cant run the app in emulator, the emulator shows the app stopped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try ionic run android -l -c to check error on cli